# Tensorflow Version selection in Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I am trying to use the [TF object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) in Google Colab. It does not support TF2.x, and one of the modules the API requires is `tf.contrib`, which is in TF 1.x, [including TF 1.15](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib).

For my own code (which I obviously still need to work) I specify:

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

I have tried:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

and

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

with and without

```
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

`print(tf.__version__)` confirms it is 1.15.2

However executing the model_builder_test.py file returns the no attribute 'contrib' error.

If I do not import anything beforehand, then that part executes perfectly. Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance for saving me another 4 hours!

Comment: It's important to execute the `%tensorflow_version` command *before* you `import tensorflow`. Otherwise, when you switch the version, the Python runtime will need to be restarted to pick up the switch. (You can do this via the Runtime -> Restart menu.)

Comment: @BobSmith Already done thanks, the tf.__version__ line confirms it. Any other ides?